# Inconsistent UserAgent strings with IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, iis-6, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

I have a website running on a server in IIS6. The website is configured with two hostheader bindings on port 80:

- **mywebsite1** *<- requires an entry in local windows hosts file to fake a DNS entry*
- **mywebsite2.mydomain.com** *<- uses DNS*

So, in theory using a web browser to access either:

- http://mywebsite1/
- http://mywebsite2.mydomain.com/

...should both show the exact same website in my browser.

However, when I use IE9 to view http://mywebsite1/, the UserAgent that the browser sends to the web server is this:

```
Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+Trident/5.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+Media+Center+PC+6.0;+Tablet+PC+2.0;+MS-RTC+LM+8;+OfficeLiveConnector.1.5;+OfficeLivePatch.1.3;+.NET4.0C)
```

But when I use IE9 to view http://mywebsite2.mydomain.com/, the UserAgent that the browser sends to the web server is this:

```
Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+9.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+Trident/5.0)
```

Why would IE9 send a different UserAgent string in these two situations? The browser is also emulating the rendering rules for these user agents, so this is causing nightmare CSS problems!

Additional info:

- I have included  in the page head tag.
- The website is ASP.NET Framework 3.
- The web server is IIS 6.
- The web browser is IE9.
- (let me know if you want me to clarify anything else)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE9 [reports](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/03/23/introducing-ie9-s-user-agent-string.aspx) `Mozilla/4.0` when in Compatibility View, did you click the "torn page" icon when viewing your http://mywebsite1/ ? (The view can also be [requested](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956197) by the html thats served.)

Comment: Ah yes, that makes both URLs consistent, but actually it's the other hostheader version that shows the "torn page" icon. http://mywebsite1/ does not show a "torn page" icon. What triggers the torn page to show in IE9?

Comment: Response headers from the server or a meta tag in the HTML can do it, or if you mis-click and set the view, it sticks - take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726357/why-does-ie9-switch-to-compatibility-mode-on-my-website

Answer (score 0):

This will change the useragent; however, when I change the useragent it will be for only the site i'm on and i surf the web the useragent will go back to it's default. This what I use for the code to change the useragent

WebBrowser1.Navigate(txtAddressBar.Text, Nothing, Nothing, "user-agent:" & "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/532.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) ChromePlus/4.0.222.3 Chrome/4.0.222.3 Safari/532.2")

This code post to be one line; however, I don't know how to do that on here yet.