# HTML5 Canvas hosted on Dropbox doesn't work with IE9

Tags: html, canvas, internet-explorer-9, dropbox

Try this link on Firefox or Chrome:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/34375299/aaa/index.html

Notice a simple animation appears on a HTML5 canvas there.

Load the same link in IE9, and it displays the fallback content inside the canvas tag: "Your browser does not appear to support HTML5..." - but IE9 has perfectly good canvas support!

I'm using `<!DOCTYPE html>`, and if all the necessary files are downloaded and run in IE9 from disk, it works OK.  Also, the same page hosted on other providers (e.g. normal web servers rather than dropbox), it also works OK.

What's different about dropbox that means IE9 won't show a canvas, and can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to make sure that your IE9 is not in Compatibility Mode, which would force it behave like IE8, which doesn't support canvas. I'm guessing something on the dropbox site is forcing your browser into compatibility mode. See this answer for more details on that... [Why does IE9 switch to compatibility mode on my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726357/why-does-ie9-switch-to-compatibility-mode-on-my-website)

Comment: Thanks, `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` did the trick!

Answer (score 2):

Unsure as to why this is happening, but it is going into IE 9 compatability mode instead of rending in standards mode. You can try forcing it with the following meta element: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" >`