# How can I create alternating background colors for listview rows while only using ItemTemplate?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview, alternating

How can I create alternating background colors for listview rows while only using ItemTemplate?  I don't want to use AlternateTemplate because I would have to edit both of them everytime i want to change something when all I'm using it for is to create the alternating background colors.  So what's a way I could do it using only the ItemTemplate? Thanks!

Comment: You can insert a literal tag that you render the appropriate CSS into. Unfortunately, I'm not a VB buff, but that should get you on the right path.

Comment: Cool Thanks I'll look into it and post back with my solution thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you could consider the alternating colours a progressive enhancement and not absolutely required in all (old) browsers then you could use a CSS n-th child selector to apply the colour without changing the HTML.

If you have jQuery (or similar) in your project already and want a solution for older browser, you could use that to select every other row with the :odd or :even selector.

Update (Example)

Assuming we are using table rows

```
tr:nth-child(odd) td{  
  background-color: red;  
}
```

You can also use `even`, `2n` or `2n+1`. This would work equally well with `<li>` tags.

More examples: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild

Comment: +1 I've upvoted your answer since it's the best but could you post a little example of how to do it with CSS? Or at least to a post where one can see how is done? Just for completeness sake...

Comment: This works for me in Chrome but not IE9 :(  I even disabled the compatibility mode for intranet sites. Any ideas?

Comment: That'll be because IE9 is in compatibility mode. Check out this question for possible causes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726357/why-does-ie9-switch-to-compatibility-mode-on-my-website

Answer (score 2):

This might work too:

[Alternating Table Row Colors with ASP.Net ListView Control](http://www.somacon.com/p543.php)

It uses the ***<%#*** style syntax in your ASPX page to toggle the class based on the DisplayIndex Mod 2.

C# and VB code samples on that link too...

Answer (score 1):

Use the ItemDataBound event of the ListView (if it has one like the Repeater does). Add a runat="server" element to your ItemTemplate that you can use to set the color using a class. Get a reference to this control in the event and set the css class.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a Repeater control, instead of the ListView.

You'll have more control over the template, and it's easier to change alternating colors, w/out having duplicate templates.