# force website render doctype html5 standard & IE9 browser

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, doctype

We have an html5 standard website; everything renders perfectly when viewed from a test webhost site server.

Ideally...from the client's Learning Management System (LMS), when the user launches the html5 website, the html5 site will appear in a popup.

But, the client's LMS is not compatible with html5 or IE9 (IE is, unfortunately, the default/preferred browser).

The client's launch page AND the popup that contain the html5 site are both set to older doctypes and have IE7 meta tagging. If a user hits F12 and tries to change the Document Mode: from Quirks (which is what the popup is showing) to IE9, the site still doesn't render properly.

Is there any way to force the client's LMS to open the html5 site with the proper [!DOCTYPE html] and/or Document Mode: IE9?

Thanks for your insight!

Comment: I'm not quite sure from the question, do you have access to the source HTML of the popup? Or you're unable to modify any of the HTML on their side?

Comment: Hi Trolleymusic, thank you for your comment...no, unfortunately I have no access to their side (source HTML or popup) and can't edit anything within their LMS. Which in my opinion, puts the onus on them to fix their system to allow for HTML5/IE9.

Comment: Did you have any luck with the headings (see below) ?

Comment: Use [XHTML5 markup](http://debeterevormgever.nl/en/articles/html5-elements-ie-without-javascript/example-xhtml) to override the doctype.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726357/why-does-ie9-switch-to-compatibility-mode-on-my-website

Answer (score 4):

Yeah I think you're right that puts it on them. If you did have access you could put this tag in the head: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` which will tell IE to render it as well as it can.

You might try checking what headers are coming down from the server too - if you've got Firebug you can see it in the **Net** tab. Just open a page on their side and look at the **Response Headers** under the first `GET sitename.com`. I had a client a while ago and their site was showing as IE7 standards on all versions of IE (7+) - and it was because they had a `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7">` header set in IIS...

It just seems suspicious that if the popup is all your code, and all valid, that it still renders in quirks mode.

Comment: Note you missed the / off the closing tag. I have added it for you

Comment: Thanks, but afaik the `/` is optional when you're using the HTML5 doctype -- http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/syntax.html#void-element & example: https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/index.html