# IE: Broken Content area in Compatability View

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, cross-browser

I hate IE. That being said, one dilemma I can't seem to solve.

http://cypresshh2.cakuun.com/

When in Compatability mode in IE9, the content falls. Out of CV mode, it's fine. Any thoughts?

Comment: Compatibility Mode isn't technically an IE "version", and most designers don't typically design for it or worry about it. It displays pages similar to IE6, which hardly(shouldn't) exists anymore. You can Google techniques on how to avoid IE defaulting to comp. mode or there's a good thread on SO at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726357/why-does-ie9-switch-to-compatibility-mode-on-my-website . However, if you're dead set on it I can help you further.

Comment: `min-height` doesn't work for all elements in IE<8. Read more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530815(v=vs.85).aspx