# IE9 keep switching to Compatibility mode on my site

Tags: internet-explorer-9, compatibility

I have read this post [Why does IE9 switch to compatibility mode on my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726357/why-does-ie9-switch-to-compatibility-mode-on-my-website) but this does not solve my problem with compatibility mode. And this only happens to 3 of the page on the site. Whenever I visit those page on IE9, a bubble will pop out and say that there is some problem and refresh into Compatibility mode.

The pages actually look entirely correct in normal mode and look like hell in Compatibility mode.

Does anyone have any idea what is triggering the compatibility mode? The only common part in these 3 pages are the gallery, but I also put the galleries on another page, an d that page does not refresh into o\compatibility mode.

This is my site: 
http://rebuild.silverridgeal.com/texas-dementia-care-facilities

---

Problem solved, I just need to put the META tag as high as possible within the HEAD tag to be recognized.

Comment: What are the 3 pages with the problem?

Comment: Pretty good discussion about IE compatibility modes here - [Understanding Compatibility Modes in Internet Explorer 8](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/03/23/understanding-compatibility-modes-in-internet-explorer-8.aspx)  It is from IE 8 because that is when the feature was introduced. Be sure to read the comments  too.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I have found the solution. It turns out that I did not put the META tag high enough within the <head> tag.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing similar problem. For me, jquery and customized $.delay function is causing this issue. When I comment that code its works normally. I am developing single HTML page (100% AJAX ) web-app. So page reload is not happening..

Even I am still wondering how come jquery code or JS setTimeout triggering the IE to go for older mode.

Its very strange IE issue. Microsoft should address it with some patch.

Please check in your code whether you have used similar JS or jquery function which might be triggering this.

Also check for META tag of those three pages.