# MVC / Internet Explorer 10 defaults to Compatibility View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, internet-explorer

I use Remote Desktop to access a Windows 8 PC.

In my MVC 4 controller, I've got this code on the first request:

```
If Request.Browser.Browser.ToLower = "ie" Then
    If CDec(Request.Browser.Version.Replace(".", ",")) < 9 Then
        Response.Redirect("browser_too_old.html", True)
        Exit Function
    End If
End If
```

But when I use Remote Desktop to log on to my Windows 8 PC, Internet Explorer defaults to version 7 (Compatibility View):

> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0;
>   .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR
>   3.0.30729; InfoPath.3)

Since I'm using controller (no webpage has yet been loaded), I can't use this:

> meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"

How do I force it to be IE10 (that is - not Compatibility View)?

Comment: Add doctype. Also, on the first request, all bets are off (because you still haven't transmitted any headers/content yet).

Comment: And if you send the actual HTTP header rather than using a meta element?

Comment: Just a sidenote, but "forceful upgrading" is a quite agressive counterpart of "progressive enhancement".

Comment: @CodeCaster Meh. Google doesn't support IE8 anymore, also Microsoft's own "Microsoft Downloads" doesn't work in IE8, so yeah...

Comment: @Alexander not supporting is not the same as blatantly refusing access and besides that, there are better ways to detect browser capabilities than through user-agent sniffing. Anyway not my project, just a helpful remark, OP can choose to do whatever he wishes.

Comment: @Alexander - but I'm in the controller (first request from the user), no page has yet been rendered, so I can't use doctype.

Comment: @CodeCaster - jquery 2.0 doesn't support IE < 9, so we want to force our clients to update or use another browser.

Comment: IE defaults to display local/intranet sites in compatibility mode. "You can change these settings from ‘Tools -> Compatibility view settings’ from the IE menu. Of course that menu is now sneakily hidden, so you won't see it until you press Alt." Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726357/why-does-ie9-switch-to-compatibility-mode-on-my-website

Comment: And I think it's a mistake to not care for IE8 at this point. There are still many people out there who are not willing to upgrade from Windows XP (and after experiencing Windows Vista, I don't really blame them). Do we really want to alienate all of them?

Comment: @philreed ... thanks - that did the trick. Post it as an answer and I mark it answered. :)

Comment: @Mr. Lister - Well in a few months, we're using IE11, so I see no problem than telling my customers, that if they want to use my website ... upgrade. The faster everybody does that, the faster people upgrades their browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE defaults to display local/intranet sites in compatibility mode.

"You can change these settings from ‘Tools -> Compatibility view settings’ from the IE menu. Of course that menu is now sneakily hidden, so you won't see it until you press Alt."

Source: [Why does IE9 switch to compatibility mode on my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726357/why-does-ie9-switch-to-compatibility-mode-on-my-website)