# css3 works on jfiddle but not on IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

This is my simple code
http://jsfiddle.net/6hLf6/1/

when I open the jsfiddle on my IE, it is working perfectly.

but when I open the code locally, it looks like this:
[image]

I am using IE11

this is my css

```
#loading {
            margin: 80px auto;
            position: relative;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
               -moz-border-radius: 50px;
                    border-radius: 50px;
            background: #ccc;
            font: 12px "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 100px;
            color: white;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
            box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

        }
        #loading:before {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
              left: -20px;
               top: -20px;
            bottom: -20px;
             right: -20px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 70px;
               -moz-border-radius: 70px;
                    border-radius: 70px;
            background: #eee;
            z-index: -2;
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
            -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        }
        #loading span {
            position: absolute;
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            border-left: 50px solid transparent;
            border-right: 50px solid transparent;
            border-top: 80px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
            z-index: -1;
            top: -28px;
            left: 0px;
            -webkit-animation: ticktock 5s linear infinite;
            -moz-animation: ticktock 5s linear infinite;
            animation:ticktock 5s linear infinite;
            -webkit-transform-origin: 50px 80px;
            -moz-transform-origin: 50px 80px;
            transform-origin:50px 80px;
        }
        #loading strong {
            overflow: hidden;
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
            -webkit-animation: expand 2.5s linear infinite;
            -moz-animation: expand 2.5s linear infinite;
            animation:expand 2.5s linear infinite;
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes expand {
            0% {
                    width: 0;
            }
            100% {
                    width: 60px;
            }
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes ticktock {
            0% {
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
                    -ms-transform: rotate(0);
                    -moz-transform: rotate(0);
            }
            100% {
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
                    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
                    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
            }
        }

        @-moz-keyframes expand {
            0% {
                    width: 0;
            }
            100% {
                    width: 60px;
            }
        }

        @-moz-keyframes ticktock {
            0% {
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
                    -ms-transform: rotate(0);
                    -moz-transform: rotate(0);
            }
            100% {
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
                    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
                    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
            }
        }



        @keyframes ticktock {
            0% {
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
                    -ms-transform: rotate(0);
                    -moz-transform: rotate(0);
            }
            100% {
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
                    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
                    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
            }
        }


        @keyframes expand {
            0% {
                    width: 0;
            }
            100% {
                    width: 60px;
            }
        }
```

I tried to handle the css on IE, that is why it is working on jfiddle but not when I run the code on localhost.

what should I do plesae?

Edit
html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="loading.css"/>
</head>
<body>

        <div id="loading"><strong>loading...</strong><span></span></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you in compatibility mode?

Comment: @SLaks I don't know, what is that please and how to know if i am on compatibiity mode or not

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I edited the question and added the html, you can check the jsfiddle if you want

Comment: Look in the dev tools.

Comment: @SLaks I clicked f12 and the tool is opened, but then what to do to know compatibility or not? thanks

Comment: The problem is not reproducible in IE 11 on Windows 7, whether in “standards mode” or in “quirks mode” (compatibility mode). Is there anything in the local HTML file that has not been disclosed?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela no everything is closed, I gave you all the code in the edited question

Comment: This is strange. My IE 11 shows it OK even if I force the browser into quirks mode—but not if I make it emulate IE 8 or older. And in IE 7 emulation the result is as in the image in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using XHTML 1.0 strict the following HTML works with your CSS to provide the desired effect.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="loading">
        <strong>loading...</strong>
        <span></span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please compare the above code with the HTML you are using.

---

Edit:

I managed to replicate your error by enabling compatibility mode. Please click on the gear in the top right of internet explorer then click compatibility view settings and check your domain is not on the 'websites you've added to compatibility view' list if it is remove it from the list. Also un-check display intranet sites in compatibility view. Then try opening it.

Comment: If this doesn't make sense please post your HTML and I will have a look.

Comment: your solution didn't change anything in my problem, i added the whole html, kindly check the edited question

Comment: @Marco Dinatsoli let me know what happens when you try this.

Comment: the result is still the rectangle div that i showed you in this question, but when i put the code in jsfiddle, it works perfectly. could u help please? sure it is something in my ie

Comment: You could try Internet Options > Advance > reset internet explorer settings. To rest all of the options on your browser if that doesn't work then it is not an option within IE causing the problem.

Comment: restarting the computer, solves the problem. many thanks for your efforts man

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

At the top of your code otherwise the page will not be displayed using ie 11

Comment: Good guess, but IE 11 seems to support the relevant CSS properties in compatibility mode, too.