# Does SonarQube 4.5.1 support Internet Explorer 8, 9 and 10?

Tags: internet-explorer, sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

I am currently using SonarQube 4.5.1 and it works fine in Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox and Internet Explorer 11. But when I open UI in IE 8 and 9, I got this error:

> The web interface cannot be displayed because your browser is not supported.Please switch to a supported version or another supported browser.

I tried solution from this [link](http://sonarqube-archive.15.x6.nabble.com/IE-10-support-td5026022.html) - but no luck.

Does SonarQube 4.5.1 support IE 8, 9 and 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for IE9 and IE10 has been dropped in SonarQube 5.3 (see [SONAR-6955](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6955)).

I think you open page in compatibility mode. Please read this to resolve this problem: [Why does IE9 switch to compatibility mode on my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3726357/4944847)